# Good methods to get notified on an android phone if a websites element has a certain value?

Tags: android, html, element

I am searching for a method to get notified on my android phone, if the first occurrence of a element of a certain class has a value larger than x on a multiple times a minute updated website.

Though this website is not subject to constant updates, here is an example using amazons "[100 Books to Read in a Lifetime](https://www.amazon.com/b/ref=bhp_brws_100bks?ie=UTF8&node=8192263011)":
Currently the first book on the site is sold for $5.99. I would like to be notified on my phone, if it is offered for 5.50 or less. Therefore I would need to implement a method to retrieve the price inside the first occurrence of `<span class="a-size-base a-color-price acs_product-price__buying">`(`$5.99</span>`),  check if the number substring is smaller or equal to 5.5 and notify me on my phone.

Keep in mind, amazon is just an example, I am in search for a general and customizable solution on an often changing website.

What would be a good way of implementing such a notification system?

---

P.S.: This is my first post on stackoverflow. If you think I should add something or rephrase my question, please let me know!

Comment: This question is far too broad. Please edit your question to limit it to something more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSOUP](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup) for parsing the html code and then using the selector to get the value of the item, And for the changes in price you have to schedule a job which will run in background and check for updates in a given interval of time, Save the price in device locally on every request and while doing the next request compare the value and if there is any change in value show notification.